# how to save dynamically generated html page without using execCommand() using javascript

Tags: javascript

Window.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, 'new.txt');
    i don't want to use this because it pops-up windows explorer.
    i want to directly save it to current working directory.

Comment: Saving to a directory on the hard drive is a security risk.  Hence the popup box.

Comment: so, there's no way to work in this manner?

Comment: @Kittu Yes, it's a security policy. Imagine a user who opens the site and without his knowledge some files are saved on his computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server)